# ListView with RadioGroup not displaying

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I want to create a `ListView` that holds list items that have a `CheckBox` and a `RadioGroup` with 2 `RadioButtons`.

I am not sure why, but `TextView`'s and `CheckBox` are displaying, and the `RadioGroup` isn't.

I have looked up the problem, but couldn't find this exact issue. Can anyone help me?

This is the XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:id="@+id/hlInteraction"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/hlInteraction"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/rgInteraction"
    >
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:text="@string/rb_on"
        android:id="@+id/rbTurnOff"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:text="@string/rb_off"
        android:id="@+id/rbTurnOn"
        />
    </RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvDeviceNameInteraction"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_above="@id/rgInteraction"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvDeviceDistanceInteraction"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvDeviceNameInteraction"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_above="@id/rgInteraction"
    />
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/cbInteraction"
    android:layout_above="@id/rgInteraction"
    />
```

And here is the custom adatper class:

```
public class InteractionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Interaction>
{
    private ArrayList<Interaction> mList;
    private Context mContext;

    /*
     * Creates the Adapter for the list
     */
    public InteractionAdapter(Context context, int layoutId, ArrayList<Interaction> list)
    {
        super(context,layoutId,list);
        mList = list;
        mContext = context;

    }
    /**
     * inflate view for each row
     */
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        Interaction current = mList.get(position);
        /* if the given channel row view is not being updated*/
        if (v == null) {
            /* inflate layout */
            LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_interaction, null, false);
        }

        /*get the component pointers */
        TextView tvInteractionDeviceName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDeviceNameInteraction);
        TextView tvInteractionDeviceDistance = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDeviceDistanceInteraction);


        RadioButton rbOn = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.rbTurnOn);
        RadioButton rbOff =  (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.rbTurnOff);
        rbOn.setChecked(true);

        CheckBox cbInteraction =  (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.cbInteraction);

        Device d = current.getDevice();//Gets Device object and then BluettothDevice object

        tvInteractionDeviceName.setText(d.getDevice().getName());
        tvInteractionDeviceDistance.setText(String.valueOf(d.getRSSI()));

        return v;
    }
```

Also if i wanted to get the states of the `RadioButton`s i basically need to add tags to them as a form of labeling so that i can distinguish one from the other. Right?

**EDIT**
The layout seems to be working fine in the preview i just posted xml code for you to see. I doubt there is any mistake in that part of the code.

Here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: i have posted a new answer this code is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have try it all myself. This pieace of code is working fine, the problem is there in your layout. With the view layout you were using. Here is the whole code.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.helppeople;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView mLists;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mLists = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    ArrayList<Interaction> mList = new ArrayList<Interaction>();

    mList.add(new Interaction("123"));
    mList.add(new Interaction("456"));
    mList.add(new Interaction("789"));
    mList.add(new Interaction("012"));

    InteractionAdapter mAdapter = new InteractionAdapter(
            getApplicationContext(), mList);

    mLists.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

list_item_interaction.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rgInteraction"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbTurnOff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="asdasd" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbTurnOn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="asdas" />
</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDeviceNameInteraction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/rgInteraction"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDeviceDistanceInteraction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/rgInteraction"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvDeviceNameInteraction"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cbInteraction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/rgInteraction"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingRight="4dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

InteractionAdapter.java

```
package com.example.helppeople;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class InteractionAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<Interaction> mList;
private Context mContext;

/*
 * Creates the Adapter for the list
 */
public InteractionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Interaction> list) {
    mList = list;
    mContext = context;

}

/**
 * inflate view for each row
 */
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    Interaction current = mList.get(position);
    /* if the given channel row view is not being updated */
    if (v == null) {
        /* inflate layout */
        LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_interaction, null, false);
    }

    /* get the component pointers */
    TextView tvInteractionDeviceName = (TextView) v
            .findViewById(R.id.tvDeviceNameInteraction);
    TextView tvInteractionDeviceDistance = (TextView) v
            .findViewById(R.id.tvDeviceDistanceInteraction);

    RadioButton rbOn = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.rbTurnOn);
    RadioButton rbOff = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.rbTurnOff);
    rbOn.setChecked(true);

    CheckBox cbInteraction = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.cbInteraction);

    // Gets Device object and then BluettothDevice object

    tvInteractionDeviceName.setText("abc");
    tvInteractionDeviceDistance.setText("xyxz");

    return v;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return mList.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
    }
}
```

Interaction.java

```
package com.example.helppeople;

public class Interaction {

String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Interaction(String name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, your solution fixed my problem. I am grateful! :)

Answer (score 0):

first of all i have improved your layout a bit

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<View
    android:id="@+id/hlInteraction"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rgInteraction"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/hlInteraction"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbTurnOff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="asdasd" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbTurnOn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="asdas" />
</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDeviceNameInteraction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/rgInteraction"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDeviceDistanceInteraction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/rgInteraction"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvDeviceNameInteraction"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cbInteraction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/rgInteraction"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingRight="4dp" />
```

but displaying of radio button has nothing to do with this, i think that you must use radiogroup

```
 RadioGroup radiogroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

        radiogroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // Radio button
                RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButtonID);
                if (rb1.isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "1 option selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "2 option selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        });
```

try this, don't use @SuppressLint("InflateParams"), use

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_interaction, parent, false);
```

Comment: tell me if it help, hope it helps... i haven't test run this code but I do think so that it is the problem

Comment: The corrected XML code did not help. And not sure how this 2nd part of the code can help... Also tried it, not working...

Comment: @PavlePavlov see if it help, and do let me know. I have edited my answer don't use @SuppressLint("InflateParams") but use convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_interaction, parent, false); instead

Comment: Still the same result. :/

Comment: wait i will try my self all then post the answer

Comment: @PavlePavlov i have posted the answer now chill name and smile. Happy coding like this :) not like :/

Answer (score 0):

Pavle,
Firstly, check in your xml preview mode if your radio button is showing up in the particular row or not,if not then definitely your layout design is not proper.
If so, then we can work out on the layout.

Comment: Please add some more code for this. This will not be accepted as a answer you need to add some code for this

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this:

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(r.id.rgInteraction);
// This will get the radiobutton in the radiogroup that is checked 
RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton)radioGroup.findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
```

Use Listner like this:

```
// This overrides the radiogroup onCheckListener 

 radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    { 
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checkedId)
        { 
            // This will get the radiobutton that has changed in its check state 
            RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton)radioGroup.findViewById(checkedId);
            // This puts the value (true/false) into the variable 
            boolean isChecked = checkedRadioButton.isChecked();
            // If the radiobutton that has changed in check state is now checked... 

            if (isChecked){ 
                Toast.makeText(InteractionAdapter.this, "Checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else{
                Toast.makeText(InteractionAdapter.this, "Unchecked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } 
    });
```